# How to change the default path of Sitefinity media/images/

Tags: sitefinity

Our images in Sitefinity are located in this path domain.com/media/images/ Is it possible to change the path to this? Example: domain.com/~/media/images/

Answer (score 0):

You can change the **URL Root** of the image libraries from the

```
Administration > Settings > Advanced > Libraries > Images
```

So, in theory, if you set the url root from `images` to `~/images` it should work after a restart, but it didn't in my tests.

What's the reason behind this requirement?